# Prometheus relabeling/metricRelabeling to drop and filter by labels

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am having no luck configuring prometheus relabeling. If I have series like

```
some_metric{app="foo",baz="true"}
some_metric{app="bar",baz="true"}
```

How do I configure prometheus (currently using the coreos operator if that matters), to keep only `app=foo` and drop the label `baz`, so that I end up with:

```
some_metric{app="foo"}
```

For what it's worth, here's what I currently have and the labels are showing up as is:

```
- action: keep
  sourceLabels: ["app"]
  regex: "foo"
- action: labeldrop
  regex: "baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
- action: labeldrop
  regex: baz
- action: drop
  source_labels: [app]
  regex: bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with drop is that I have to tell it everything to match against to drop, which I don't know up front. I do know what I want to `keep`, which is just  `foo`.

Comment: you with drop we cannot use wildcard *?

Comment: @bschaeffer you have `labelkeep` which is to match against all label names. Any label that does not match will be removed from the set of labels.